# How to get a parent tag in nested XML in java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XML file like below:

```
  <main>
       <member>
           <tag1>
              <id>"123"</id> 
           </tag1>
       </member> 
       <member>
           <tag1>
              <id>"222"</id>
              <first>
                <code>"1"</code>
                <name>"x"<name>
              </first>
           </tag1>
       </member>
       <member>
           <tag1>
               <id>"321"</id> 
           </tag1>
       </member>  
       <member>
           <tag1>
              <id>"333"</id>
              <second>
                <code>"1"</code>
                <name>"y"<name>
              </second>
              <first>
                <code>"2"</code>
                <name>"z"<name>
              </first>  
           </tag1>
       </member> 
  </main>
```

I am able to loop through the list and get the "name" value in a list. I should print results in a CSV file which has columns such as "First name" and "second name" so at the time that I am reading these names I need to know which name is associated with which "parent" tag. In other words, I need to insert name under the tag "First" in the "First name" column and name under "second" tag under "second name". 
So at the time that I am looping through I should check if the parent is "first" insert the name into "First name" and so on.
 I have name Element as follow:

```
  NodeList nameList=doc.getElementsByTagName("tag1");
  ...//some code to parse throught the rest of the elements
  for (int temp = 0; temp < nameList.getLength(); temp++) {
       Node nNode = nameList.item(temp);
       if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
          Element nElement=(Element) nNode;
          System.out.println(nElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(temp).getTextContent());
        }
   }
```

If I use the following to check it will give me "member1".

```
  nElement.getParentNode().getNodeName()
```

How can I get "first" or "second" as parents of "name"? Or is there a better way to do this?

Note: the above code is part of my code which is really big because there are a lot of tags in this XML that needs to be parsed. I just added partial part of the code that is required for the information. If more is required, please let me know so that I can update my question.

I used XPath to solve the problem but still not getting the answer :

```
        String expression="/main/member";
        String fExpression="/main/member/tag1/first";
        String sExpression="/main/member/tag1/second";
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);


        for (int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength();i++){
            Node nNode=nodeList.item(i);
            NodeList pLangList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(fExpression).evaluate(nNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList sLangList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(sExpression).evaluate(nNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            Node flangNode=pLangList.item(i);
            Node slangNode=sLangList.item(i);
            if (flangNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element fLangElement=(Element) plangNode;
                System.out.println(i+"# primary"+fLangElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
             }
            if (slangNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                 Element sLangElement=(Element) slangNode;
                 System.out.println(i+"# secondary"+sLangElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
             }
             //rest of the code
        }
```

I used XPath but here is the issue: in the loop from 0 to length of the list, in iteration 0 it prints both x and y then on iteration 1, it prints z. where it should print x on iteration 1 and y, z on iteration 2! How do I solve this?

Note: I have updated the code with recent changes and still having same problem plus an error as follow:

```
0# first x
0# second y 
1# first z
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly address the needed elements using xpath (java code part is all yours ;) )

Get 'member' tags and iterate them

```
String expression = "//member"";
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Then for each of those nodes, get the other tags referencing the current node

```
String namex = "//tag1/name/text()";
NodeList namenodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(namex).evaluate(nNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Note that the first argument for evaluate() is the current 'node' and not 'doc'.

Comment: I used XPath but here is the issue: in the loop from 0 to length of the list, in iteration 0 it prints both x and y then on iteration 1, it prints z. where it should print x on iteration one and y, z on iteration 2! How do I solve this?

Comment: Please, update your question with the actual code you are testing.

Comment: Luis thank you for helping me, I did the changes and I am still seeing the same issue, I'll update the question with the recent changes that I made. Would you please take a look and help me figure this thing out?!

Comment: 1- the name xpath must be changed to the relative to the current node, chck my answer. 2- You should check pLanList list length before asking for item(i)

Comment: In your answer the second part in the 'evaluate()' you put 'node' wherein the first section you defined a NodeList named 'nodeList' 
Since I am assigning the plangList inside the loop I assume that everytime nNode is a new node created by item(i) so having nNode in the evaluate sounds like a relative nNode for each iteration.

Comment: Should be nNode, i.e. the node you are currently handling in the loop. You use it in evaluate() to find tags relative to it. doc is used at the start to find member tags. Then each of those member nodes are used as the reference node to search for name. In other words nNode are the existing 'member tags'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163745/discussion-between-rubbic-and-luis-munoz).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem as follow:

```
NodeList nameList=doc.getElementsByTagName("tag1");
...//some code to parse throught the rest of the elements
for (int temp = 0; temp < nameList.getLength(); temp++) {
   Node nNode = nameList.item(temp);
   if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
      Element nElement=(Element) nNode;
      int count=getChildElementCount(nElement); //it'll return the number of child nodes if there is any
      if (count==1)
             System.out.println(temp+" # "+nElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
      else{
          NodeList childNodes=nElement.getChildNodes();
          int j=0;
          for (int i=0;i<childNodes.getLength();i++){
                if (childNodes.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && j<count){
                                     if(childNodes.item(i).getNodeName().contentEquals("second")){
                                        //do something
                                        j++;
                                     }
                                      if(childNodes.item(i).getNodeName().contentEquals("first")){
                                       //do somehting
                                        j++;
                                     }
                                 }

                             }
                         }
```